# Find eigenvalues of Complex valued matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I need to find the eigenvvalues of of this matrix, and similar such matrices (spaces denote separators):

```
[[1.0000 -0.7071*I 0 -0.7071*I 0 0 0 0 0]    
 [0.7071*I 0.5000 -0.7071*I 0 -0.70710*I 0 0 0 0]    
 [0 0.7071*I 1.0000 0 0 -0.7071*I 0 0 0]   
 [0.7071*I 0 0 0.5000 -0.7071*I 0 -0.7071*I 0 0]    
 [0 0.7071*I 0 0.7071*I 0 -0.7071*I 0 -0.7071*I 0]    
 [0 0 0.7071*I 0 0.7071*I 0.5000 0 0 -0.7071*I]    
 [0 0 0 0.7071*I 0 0 1.0000 -0.7071*I 0]    
 [0 0 0 0 0.7071*I 0 0.7071*I 0.5000 -0.7071*I]    
 [0 0 0 0 0 0.7071*I 0 0.7071*I 1.000]]
```

**Error:**
`numpy.linalg.eigvalsh()` gives error "can't convert complex to float".

What could be the reason, and how do I find eigenvalues?

Comment: please post your matrix in a usable way

Comment: In the documentation (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigvalsh.html) it clearly states that `numpy.linalg.eigvalsh` is for real or hermitian matrices only. Yours is complex. Why should it work? You have to do it the way @Glostas suggests below

Comment: It is a Hermiatian matrix.

Comment: @AdityaVijaykumar so if you try to calculate its conjugate transpose like it is done here (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.H.html) and test the two for equality you will get `True` back ? The diagonal has to be real for it to be a hermitian

Comment: I had no problem using `np.linalg.eigvalsh` on your data after translating the strange `I` to the python complex `1j` and putting it all in a `np.ndarray`. Post complete code, because it seems to be an issue with your input.

And yes, the matrix above *Is* hermitian.

Comment: @HannesOvrén so the first term is just `1.0000..`? Not `1.00-0.707*i`?

Comment: I assumed that all spaces are element dividers, so yes. At least it is a 9x9 hermitian matrix if you do it like that. But OP needs to clarify the data I think.

Answer (score 1):

As more than one commenter has explained, your matrix works fine with `eigvalsh`.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eigvalsh

I = 1j
arr = np.array([[1.0000, -0.7071*I, 0, -0.7071*I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0.7071*I, 0.5000, -0.7071*I, 0, -0.70710*I, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0.7071*I, 1.0000, 0, 0, -0.7071*I, 0, 0, 0],
    [0.7071*I, 0, 0, 0.5000, -0.7071*I, 0, -0.7071*I, 0, 0],
    [0, 0.7071*I, 0, 0.7071*I, 0, -0.7071*I, 0, -0.7071*I, 0],
    [0, 0, 0.7071*I, 0, 0.7071*I, 0.5000, 0, 0, -0.7071*I],
    [0, 0, 0, 0.7071*I, 0, 0, 1.0000, -0.7071*I, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0.7071*I, 0, 0.7071*I, 0.5000, -0.7071*I],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.7071*I, 0, 0.7071*I, 1.000]])

# Ensure hermitian
assert(np.all(0 == (arr - np.conj(arr.T))))

print(eigvalsh(arr))
# outputs:
# [-1.56153421 -0.2807671  -0.2807671   0.5         0.5         1.          1.7807671  1.7807671   2.56153421]
```

Answer (score -1):

In numpy you get this for free

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[1+1j,0+1j],[0+1j,1+1j]])
eingenvalues,eigenvectors=np.linalg.eig(matrix)
```

will give you both, eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectosr

If you are really only interested in the eigen values you can use

```
eingenvalues=np.linalg.eigvals(matrix)
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The question is why `eigvalsh` generated an error message.

Comment: The question is "What could be the reason, and how do I find eigenvalues?". This gives eigenvalues...